# How to link modifications in code to the right FreeType library version?

Tags: c, linux, freetype, freetype2

I am working in unix. I have added some custom code in Freetype to test its flow. I am targeting the Type1 driver module and using my client side application i am trying to open a type1 font file and print the font family name and style name from it. I have added the following code in side type1 driver module section where it checks header of font file (so it should always execute when ever i run my application) but it is not working. Freetype is compiled with out errors and i have installed it on OS with sudo make install command as well.

Code added in Freetype

```
FT_FILE *f;
f = ft_fopen("/home/sungmin/Freetype_source/freetype-2.8/include/freetype/internal/file.txt", "w+");
if (f != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(f, "Passed Passed Passed \n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Passed Passed Passed \n");
        }

    else
    {
        fprintf(f, "Error error error \n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Passed Passed Passed \n");
    }

   ft_fclose(f);
```

It looks like Freetype is not linking my custom code to right Freetype version. I can confirm that because i tried to comment all the code of function FT_Init_FreeType and called it with my application and still it worked. This means there is some Freetype installed on very low level which doesnt change even i add custom code or anything. So how can i modify that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the problem was related to dynamic linking. My application was linking with wrong libfreetype so i changed it through LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and now everything working smoothly.